# How can I extrace and replace a column dictionary into a single column in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where every entry in the column `info` is a dictionary of the form `{'name':name, 'year':year}`. I want to be able to unpack this dictionary and just replace that column such that every cell will just be `name`.

I've tried using `json_normalize` as follows

```
df = df.read_csv('file.csv')
df.dropna(subset=['info'], inplace=True)
names = pd.json_normalize(df['name'])
df['info'] = names['name']
```

This is close but I find that it introduces weird NaN values into my final df (I think it's related to losing the row indexes from dropping).

If there's an efficient way to do this without creating extra columns and deleting them, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because name and year values don't seem to be in quotes, I had trouble parsing using the dictionary. this just splits the name out. Maybe it will help.

```
data='''info
{'name':Jon, 'year':year}
{'name':Jack, 'year':year}
{'name':Joe, 'year':year}
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df['name'] = df['info'].str.split("{'name':").str[1].str.split(',').str[0]

0     Jon
1    Jack
2     Joe
Name: info, dtype: object
```